# How do you find the average speed and average velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, speed

The shuttle craft "Galileo" travels at a constant velocity of $2.73*10^3$ m/s up for $34.0$ min. and then turns around to travel $1.45*10^3$ m/s down for $15.0$ min.

a) Find its average speed.

b) Find its average velocity

Comment: Which of these do you understand: "speed", "velocity", "average"?

Comment: Velocity is a vector quantity while speed is a scalar... this understanding is important in this question.

Comment: Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433). We expect homework and homework-like problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. If you edit your question to explain (1) What you have tried, (2) the concept you have trouble with, and (3) your level of understanding, you'll be more likely to get responses.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the homework policy, i'll just remind you of the definitions.

$$Average \hspace{1mm}Speed= \frac{Distance \hspace{1mm}Traveled}{Time\hspace{1mm} of\hspace{1mm} Travel}$$

$$Average \hspace{1mm}Velocity= \frac{Displacement}{Time}$$

With this, you should be able to answer your own question.